# How to calculate output voltage of low pass filter with two resistors

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a standard low pass filter, except there is a second resistor in series with the capacitor. I am wanting to find a general equation and derive it for the voltage across the capacitor and second resistor.

Comment: Best show a schematic, to not leave anything to imagination. While you're at it, you may want to show what you did, yourself, where you got stuck. I don't think you want people to think you're using them to solve your problems, do you?

Comment: There is no *standard* low pass filter. The schematic is all revealing. Mark on that schematic what the input node is, what the output node is and what the reference node (0 volts usually) is.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with a schematic. Not a photo, try the easy schematic tool here. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think with a "standard" low-pass filter you mean to say a 1.Order LP filter. From what I get it looks something like this.

[image]

So in order to find Uaus, you go through the impedence divider. Which would look like:

[image]

s = j*W

Normally you also bring it into a normalised form, but after this point I think you can do it yourself too. Please next time also post a schematic, if you want to get better help.